# open source backup system with user-driven recovery

Tags: backup, snapshot, incremental-backup, rdiff-backup

At my old company we used NetApp, which supported a ".snapshot" feature. Whenever I did something stupid to my files, I could `cd .snapshot` and find hourly and nightly directories which contain snapshots of my current directory. I get the file I need and resume my work.

Is there anything similar in the open source world?

I find many backup projects, but they generally backup to a different machine, with no easy access for the user. I find a couple user-space filesystems which operate on top of rdiff-backup, but is there a project that ties everything together into a cohesive system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[ZFS-based filesystems](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19082-01/817-2271/gbciq/index.html) support exposure of a `.zfs/snapshot` subdirectory that functions in the same manner as the NetApp example you gave.

If you have a fileserver presenting home directories to users (via CIFS, NFS, etc.), a ZFS-based solution could provide this functionality. Options these days include [NexentaStor](http://nexentastor.org/), [Solaris](http://www.oracle.com/us/solaris/index.html), [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/), [FreeBSD](http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFS).

Answer (score 1):

In my research to find viable (and inexpensive) backup solutions, I came across the open-source software Amanda, and its enterprise version, Zmanda.

[Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/about.php) is more for archiving data to tape or other long-term storage media.  It works well for individual use or small business.

[Zmanda](http://www.zmanda.com/index.html) on the other hand satisfies what you're looking for regarding quick file/folder recovery in an open-source solution.  It is not as simple as cd .snapshot, but it is as simple as clicking a button to restore a folder from an administrative console.

Comment: Unfortunately we have no X11/gtk installed in our environment. Will this work in a pure commandline world?

Comment: @bukzor: It can be administered via CLI. The GUI is just a bonus.